# Is there a Google Sound API

Tags: java, audio

I have been recently been playing around with sound. I have always used Google APIs as much as possible such as com.google.commons

I was hoping to get a gooogle sound api in java. I find the java sound api very lacking, and when google does something, it tends to be cleaner and smaller barrier to entry.

So does it exsist?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no Google Sound API, unfortunately.

Comment: could you recommend another one other than standard java one.

Answer (score 0):

No google sound api. You might find some alternatives from this discussion:
[Any good recommendations for MP3/Sound libraries for java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86083/any-good-recommendations-for-mp3-sound-libraries-for-java)