# Java MP3 Library W/ Ability to Change Pitch and Speed

Tags: java, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any good recommendations for MP3/Sound libraries for java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86083/any-good-recommendations-for-mp3-sound-libraries-for-java)

Is there a nice to handle java lib for playing mp3 files? We need also some kind of feature to control pitch and playback speed. 
we have found JLayer but it does not have these features...

Comment: The duplicate question does not ask about pitch or playback speed.  While playing an MP3 might be a duplicate, the rest of the question is not.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java ME, the [MMAPI](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/mmapioverview/) provides interfaces for `PitchControl` and `RateControl`, controlling the playback pitch and playback rate respectively.