# Java - audio to values/variables?

Tags: java, python, audio

I'm generally looking for any language in which I can do this in, be it Java/Python/.NET.
I'm looking to programmatically convert audio to values. I know it's possible to render the waveform of audio using Java. Can I transfer the audio to values? For example, the part in the song with the highest amplitude would have the greatest value in this array.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167899/reading-an-audiofile-and-displaying-the-waveform-with-java) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879210/how-can-i-draw-sound-data-from-my-wav-file) may be of help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to get the actual audio samples from the audio, this is a very common operation and I'm sure you can do it in many languages.A good audio library to use in C# (.NET) is the NAudio library, it has many features and it relatively easy to use.